# Scan .jar file to see what it does

Tags: security, jar, exe

Is there a way to scan a .jar file to see each step that the program takes?  I just ask because I found a .jar file that will supposedly generate pdf files for me out of Tableau.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the author of the .jar file and want to make sure that I'm not getting something I don't want.

I also have a similar issue with an .exe file.  Is there a way to scan the .exe file to see the steps that it takes?

Answer (score -1):

Yes to both.

Jar is easier, there are a few jar decompilers. [Classy Shark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark) is simple to use.

There's also the JetBrains decompiler `org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler` which makes a little cleaner code, but is more complex to install.

For exe files, it depends on how it was created, if it's .Net, then you can pull it apart pretty easily with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

If the exe was written in something else, it gets much more complicated fast.